# Filtering images that completely overlap area of interest in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

I have a Sentinel 1 image collection and I want to filter the images that completely overlap my region of interest. `filterBounds()` keeps the images that partially overlap my ROI. While browsing the GEE documentation I found `ee.Filter.contains()`, however I did not understand the inputs of the function.

I tried the following but it didn't work

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD");
var S1_filtered = imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.contains(geometry))

Map.addLayer(S1_filtered)
```

where `geometry` is a rectangle that I drew on the map having the following coordinates:

```
coordinates: List (1 element)
    0: List (5 elements)
        0: [11.242486382607296,53.14196639066307]
        1: [11.720391656044796,53.14196639066307]
        2: [11.720391656044796,53.48654847659319]
        3: [11.242486382607296,53.48654847659319]
        4: [11.242486382607296,53.14196639066307]
```

When I run this code I obtain the following error message:

> Layer 1: Layer error: String: Unable to convert object to string.

How can I use `ee.Filter.contains()` to filter an image collection with a polygon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use positional (rather than named) arguments with [`ee.Filter.contains`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-filter-contains), you must pass them starting with `leftField, rightValue, ...`. That is, the first argument is a property name, and the second argument is the value to compare with. Since you want to match against the feature's main geometry, you pass the special string `'.geo'` as the property name.

```js
imageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.contains('.geo', geometry))
```

However, this will be quite slow, as this filter is not currently optimized like the extremely common intersection filter (`filterBounds`) is. So, you can improve the performance by *also* using `filterBounds()`.

It will also help to choose a date range rather than requesting a mosaic of all the S1 images ever.

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD");

var S1_filtered = imageCollection
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-02-01')
    .filter(ee.Filter.contains('.geo', geometry));

Map.addLayer(S1_filtered);
```

Comment: In which situations should I use `leftField` + `rightValue`? And in which ones should I use `rightField` + `leftValue`?

Comment: @IagoMendes You'd use them the other way around than I did if you wanted to find images completely contained _within_ the region of interest. It's just a matter of which side of the comparison is constant and which side is taken from the feature.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful to those just starting on GEE.